# Angularjs additional background appears for $modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I used the exact same code for $modal but an additional window appears in the background.

Here's the code and the screen shot.

```
                $scope.displaySaveMessage = function(size) {
                    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                        templateUrl : 'contactsSave.html',
                        controller : ModalInstanceCtrl,
                        size:size, 
                        scope:$scope,
                        resolve: {
                            save_message: function () {
                              return $scope.save_message;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
```

I can't upload the screen shot... 
I couldn't directly upload the image but it's located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoN91.png

Comment: how are you calling `displaySaveMessage()`?

Comment: Make sure that $scope.displaySaveMessage is not being called twice.

Comment: Calling from within a controller using $scope.displaySaveMessage('sm'); It's not called twice. The issue is not that it's displaying two modals but there's a larger div or window within which the modal is displaying.

Comment: modal is displaying as expected except that there's a background div or window. It's not the backdrop but an extra one. It would have helped if I could attach the screen shot.

Comment: This might help at uploading screenshot. [how-to-upload-screenshots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91716/how-to-upload-screenshots)

Comment: I know the steps but I get the message I should have 10 reputations to upload an image. In any case I updated the question with a link to image above.